# How to synchronize files between a NixOS declarative container and local system path (equivalent of docker-compose volumes functionality)?

Tags: synchronization, container, nixos, nix, docker-compose

I have NixOS 22.11 set up on a local workstation.

I use [extra-container](https://github.com/erikarvstedt/extra-container) package, which can run declarative NixOS containers like imperative containers, without system rebuilds.

I'm trying to run a demo container. It downloads and uzips `woocommerce` inside container and i want to synchronize these files between the container and my local system path.
The main purpose is to learn nix better. In a docker-compose I can could have used config like this:

```
volumes:
  - <local-path>:<container-path>
```

How can I achieve it in a NixOS container?

I tried these configs, but my local system directory remains empty:

```
fileSystems."/var/www/demo/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce" = {
    device = "/root/woocommerce";
    options = [ "bind" ];
    # noCheck = true;
  }; 
};


serviceConfig = {
  BindPaths = [ "/var/www/demo/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce:/root/woocommerce" ]
};
```

full config of `woo.nix`

```
{ pkgs, ... }:

{
  containers.demo = {
    config = {
      fileSystems."/var/www/demo/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce" = {
        device = "/root/woocommerce";
        options = [ "bind" ];
        # noCheck = true;
      };
      users.users.demo = {
        isSystemUser = true;
        createHome = true;
        group = "demo";
      };
      users.groups.demo = { };

      systemd.services.woo = {
        wantedBy = [ "multi-user.target" ];
        path = with pkgs; [ coreutils wget gzip curl unzip ];
        script = ''
          /run/current-system/sw/bin/curl -L https://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/woocommerce.7.4.1.zip -o /root/woocommerce.zip &&
          unzip /root/woocommerce.zip -d /root &&
          rm /root/woocommerce.zip
        '';
        serviceConfig = {
          BindPaths = [ "/var/www/demo/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce:/root/woocommerce" ];
          # ReadWriteDirectories = [ "/root/woocommerce" ];
        };
      };
    };
  };
  environment.systemPackages = [ pkgs.coreutils pkgs.wget pkgs.gzip pkgs.curl pkgs.unzip ];
}
```

I run it with the command:

```
sudo extra-container create --start <<EOF
$(cat woo.nix)
EOF
```

What is the best way synchronize files between a NixOS declarative container and a local system?

Answer (score 1):

The `bindMounts` option was what I needed.

```
containers.demo = {
    bindMounts = {
      "/root/woocommerce" = {
        hostPath = "/var/www/demo/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce";
        isReadOnly = false;
      };
    };

}
```